# Python code for Z-THRESH, Z-DIFF, STDEV(Z) and G-ZERO accelerometer data anomaly detector

Tags: python, iot, accelerometer

I am trying to detect anomalies using the X, Y and Z accelerometer data for a project I am working on.

I came across a paper by A. Mednis, G. Strazdins, R. Zviedris, G. Kanonirs, and L. Selavo, “Real time pothole detection using Android smartphones with accelerometers,” and  I would like to implement the **Z-THRESH, Z-DIFF, STDEV(Z) and G-ZERO** algorithms in Python. The first 3 algorithms are based on the Z accelerometer axis. The latter uses all three axis.

I am a novice in this field and I am completely lost. I would greatly appreciate your advice/code - Thanks.

Comment: This is not suitable question for Stack Overflow, you need to share some code here. That said, you can try to contact the authors with a help request. The algorithms are really quite simple. For the G-ZERO if I remember correctly you should look at the magnitude of the acceleration vector and check if it close enough to zero. See here: https://www.hackster.io/RVLAD/free-fall-detection-using-3-axis-accelerometer-06383e

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.